# this.parentNode is not a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert this this `line` jquery into `javascript`.

```
**jquery code**

jQuery(this).parent("[data-bcid='" + bcid+ "']")
```

**javascript**

```
this.parentNode(("[data-bcid='" + bcid+ "']"))
```

it is giving me error

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.parentNode is not a function
    at eval (eval at handler (core-video.js:1165), <anonymous>:1:6)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.handler (core-video.js:1165)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (core-video.js:1186)
eval @ VM3770:1
handler @ core-video.js:1165
(anonymous) @ core-video.js:1186
```

how to find parent node in javascript

Comment: What is `this`?

Comment: There is no such function as parentNode in JavaScript. There is a parentNode property, which is a property of any class that implements the DOM Node interface. To find the parentNode of any node, you just use the node name and then .parentNode. eg. document.getElementById('someElement').parentNode

Comment: Converting jQuery into JavaScript requires use of  DOM and Event interfaces that jQuery hides from you with its own replacements. The `parent` function does not exist in JS, and the parameter supplied in the post _looks_ as if its trying to a `data-` attribute value on an element. Have a look at [node.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) and [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) for more information about this particular line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **closest** to filter out the parent element

```
var el = document.querySelector('div#myDiv');
el.closest('div[someAtrr]');
```

Answer (score 0):

parentNode is a property, not a function

Right: this.parentNode

Wrong: this.parentNode()